# insert then select from single query sql/mysql/mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I want to execute 2 queries:

```
query1 = "insert into country(id, country)value('UDC:123', 'India')";
query2 = "select * from country";
```

I tried this 
[mysqli_multi_query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp)
but it didn't work.

Comment: Can't you run one, then the other? Also, provide the code that you used, please...

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is the exact code you are using, but 9/10 I have missed a space in my querys or some other small thing. I like to echo my querys out to the browsers copy into phpadmin and it will let me know if the query is wrong or if there is another issue. Like I said 9 out of 10 times it's the query.

Comment: Just a note, you don't HAVE to copy+paste on phpmyadmin to be able to see errors. There are things that can and should be done to handle error on php. You CAN, you just don't have to ^^. (BTW, I'm not the downvoter)